# Explanation in a step of proof of Gauss-Bonnet theroem

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

This question is about a step in the proof of (Global) Gauss-Bonnet theorem which I don't understand.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the third last step. How did we get $-2 \pi V_i - \pi V_{et}$ in this equation ? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is calculating $\sum\limits_{j,k}\varphi_{jk}$. $V_i$ is the number of internal vertices, and at each one the interior angles of the triangles meeting at that vertex sum to $2\pi$. $V_{et}$ is the number of vertices lying on the boundary curves $C_i$ but *not* including any of their corners; since the curves $C_i$ are smooth away from their corners, the interior angles the the triangles meeting at one of those vertices sum to $\pi$. (The very last term comes from adding up the contributions at the corners of the boundary curves $C_i$.)

Comment: Thank you! Isn't two of the interior angles of the triangle formed with $V_{et} $ as one vertex already included in $2 \pi V_i$.. Also, I know I'm not suppose to ask a different question in comment. So please pardon me. I have trouble proving $3F = 2E_i + E_e$ through induction. Any hint on this one..

Comment: For your first question, sure, but we're adding up interior angles here, vertex by vertex. For your second question, each interior edge appears in precisely two faces, and each boundary edge appears in one face. So consider $$\sum_{\text{faces }f}\sum_{\text{edges }e\subset f} 1 = 3F$$ and then change the order of summation. I'm not sure what induction the author has in mind.